# 1 liner 'pythonic' code that returns a set rather than a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I would like to do the following code, except in a neat 1-liner:

```
terms_set = set([])
for term in terms: 
    if index.has_key(term): 
        terms_set.add(index[term])
```

Is it possible to do? Must return a set.

Comment: You've tagged this [python-3.x] but you're using `has_key` which is removed from Python 3

Comment: Calling `set([])` creates a list unnecessarily. `set()` has the same result without allocating a new list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension:

```
terms_set = {index[term] for term in terms if term in index}
```

Note that `key in dict` is preferred over `dict.has_key`, which [was deprecated in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html%23dict.has_key) and is not available in Python 3.

Comment: This is the best answer imo

Comment: Yes, a comprehension is even nicer.

Comment: This is great. I have one added complexity that you might be able to help with: index[term] is actually a list of lists, and I want each element of that list to be stored, which means each element has to be made into a tuple before added to the set. I tried experimenting with a sort of nested 1 liner to loop over both the terms and then length of the resulting index[term] list of lists, but no luck.

Comment: @Craig I think you want `{tuple(t) for term in in terms for t in index[term] if term in index}` or the slightly nicer `{tuple(t) for term in terms for t in index.get(term, [])}`

Answer (score 2):

```
terms_set = set(index[term] for term in terms if index.has_key(term))
```

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you want `term_set` to contain all of the values in `index` (some dict), so long as its' key is *also* mentioned in `terms` (some iterable).  regarding both as sets, that's intersection, which is roughly, for the keys at least, `set(terms) & set(index)`, but that generates two sets, and we're actually interested in neither (we want values, not keys).  We can elide one of them with `set(terms).intersection(index)` (or visa versa, depending on which one is larger (we want the smaller on the left).

We can use our good friend `map` to get the values.

how about this?

```
term_set = map(index.get, set(terms).intersection(index))
```

or even:

```
term_set = map(index.get, index.keys() & terms)
```

(in python2.7, you would need `index.viewkeys()`)

Hmm... thinking about it, `dict.get` can return a default value (ie `None`), which we could strip out after-the fact (if it occured)

```
term_set = set(map(index.get, terms))
term_set.discard(None)
```

which construts *NO* intermediate collections (assuming python3, otherwise map should be `itertools.imap`)

Although if `None` can occur as a value in index, you'd end up having to do something tedious like:

```
sentinel = object()
term_set = {index.get(term, sentinel) for term in terms} - {sentinel}
```

which is not at all better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Since you've intersected before, `.get` will always return a non-default.

Comment: I used intersection in the first example, but in the second example, i deliberately exploit the default returning behavior of `dict.get()` to avoid creating intermediate sets and doing intersections on them.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. BTW, you could also use `index.keys() & terms` for the intersection part.

Comment: interesting bit about `dict.keys()`, i didn't know about that in python 3 (obviously not available in python 2.7)

Comment: In py2, it's `viewkeys`, which returns a "set-alike".

Comment: @georg, thanks a bunch,i've included that in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
set(index[t] for t in terms if t in index)
```

Note that `has_key` is deprecated, use `key in dict` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
terms_set = set([index[term] for term in terms if index.has_key(term)])
```

Comment: Well, I should have thought of that pretty quickly... thanks Levi!

Comment: You don't even need the intermediate list.

Comment: This creates a set of terms, not `index[term]`'s.

Comment: ^ easy to change though